# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) - how to give the -v?

Tags: xcode, linker

My iOS simulator build failed with errors:

`ld: 21318 duplicate symbols for architecture i386`
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

how do I give the `-v` to xcode? I'd want to see more details but when I give -v to `Other linker flags`, nothing more comes out

Comment: Is that the *only* message of *any* kind when you build? Usually it's part of other errors, like missing libraries or undefined symbols.

Comment: it gives tons of duplicated symbols errors.. I'd need to see what causes my classes to be defined twice and all its functions generated the duplicated symbols..

Comment: Well that's the reason for the message you ask about here. Maybe you should ask about those errors instead?

Comment: I'm curious to see the -v (verbose linker information), with that information, I think I'll be able to eliminate the duplicated symbols errors

Comment: The verbose output will show things like library search paths and other information that's not really useful in 99.999% of all cases. Your problem is most likely solvable with the output you already have.

Comment: ok, do you know how to specify the `-v` options? Would you mind to post as answer then I'll close this question.. I'm currently moving forward with `lipo`, `libtool` and `ar` tools but I am still curious :P

Comment: I searched the Apple docs but can't find it -_-"